# Autogenerate storybook stories for all components

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have a large react project, some 60+ components, that I'd like to quickly get Storybook up and running in. We're late to the game in this project but have fallen in love with it in other smaller projects.

Is there a script or util that will iterate through my components and at least create a default state for each component, referring to `propTypes` and `defaultProps` of my components? I know I can write something myself but I would love to use someone else's.